# Chrome stops updating a page when computer is idle

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Chrome apparently stops updating a page when you go idle (i.e. when the screen saver comes up).

My problem is I've written an alarm app, and it doesn't work because the Javascript stops running when the computer goes idle. Is there any way around this?

---

**Update:** After testing a few different things, it seems that Chrome *doesn't* stop updating a page, it just stops *rendering* it. So for my problem (an alarm app), this is solved.

Comment: We'd know much more if you would add some code, but a lot of sites that make things like this rely on flash.

Comment: @MarkoMackic That's not relevant. Whatever it is, it will stop running when the computer goes idle/when Chrome has decided you're idle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome read this, try with web worker :)

Comment: probably the a possible soln revolves around webworkers and nosleepjs https://github.com/richtr/NoSleep.js

Comment: *"for my problem (an alarm app), this is solved"* Please post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using requestAnimationFrame? I know Chrome explicitly pauses those callbacks, but it may not also pause setTimeout.